# SwiftUI Polyline not updating to follow user as they move

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkpolyline

I have spent a lot of time researching this question and have tried a few approaches but none have worked for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated by this Swift noob.

To gain more MapKit experience, I am trying to show the user their path with a polyline on the map that follows their movements, similar to run apps that track the user. I can track the user just fine but I cannot show a live map with a Polyline that updates as they move. When closing the map and coming back to it the polyline is updated with the missing coordinates. ** I suspect the answer to my problem relates to this :) **

[image: Showing the polyline stops updating]
Image showing the map after it loads and the user moves away from the Polyline. Closing the map and reopening redraws the missing points of the polyline

#### LocationViewModel.swift

```
    var locationArray: [CLLocation] = []
    var coordArray: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
(...)
    var coordinates2D:[CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
        var coordArray = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
        
        for c in locationArray {
            let lat = c.coordinate.latitude
            let long = c.coordinate.longitude
            
            let x = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
            
            coordArray.append(x)
            
        }
        return coordArray
    }
(...)
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       
        for newLocation in locations {
          let howRecent = newLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow
          guard newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 20 && abs(howRecent) < 10 else { continue }
          
            speeds.append(contentsOf: locationArray.map{$0.speed}) //append all new speed updates to the array
            
            altitude.append(contentsOf: locationArray.map{$0.altitude}) //append all new speed updates to the array

           
            locationArray.append(newLocation)
        }
```

#### SecondMap.swift

```
import Foundation

import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct SecondMap: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = MKMapView
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: LocationsModel
    
    @State var regionZoom = LocationService.sharedLocInstance.locationManager.location?.coordinate
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading
        
        return mapView
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        
//        uiView.removeAnnotation(uiView.annotations)
//        uiView.showAnnotations(self.locations, animated: true)
        if regionZoom != nil {
            
            let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: regionZoom!, span: span)
            uiView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            
        }
        
        
        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: model.coordinates2D, count: model.coordinates2D.count)
        uiView.removeOverlay(polyline)
        uiView.addOverlay(polyline)
        
        uiView.delegate = context.coordinator
    }
    
    static func dismantleUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, coordinator: ()) {
//        uiView.removeAnnotation(uiView.annotations)
    }
    
    //MARK: - Create Coordinator Class
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

            // If the annotation is the user dot then return nil
            if annotation is MKUserLocation {
                return nil
            }

            // Create an annotation view
            let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "business")

            annotationView.canShowCallout = false
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            annotationView.isHidden = true
            return annotationView

        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

            if let routePolyline = overlay as? MKPolyline {
                let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: routePolyline)
                renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
                renderer.lineWidth = 7
                return renderer
            }

            return MKOverlayRenderer()
        }

    }
    
    
}
```

#### TrackerDetailCard

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct TrackerDetailView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: LocationsModel
    
    @State var isMapShowing = false
    
    
//    @State var regionZoom = LocationService.sharedLocInstance.locationManager.location?.coordinate
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            if !isMapShowing {
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack{
                        
                        Text("Map info and stuff")
                        
                        Button {
                            self.isMapShowing = true
                        } label: {
                            Text("Launch Map")
                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(NEUMORPHISM_BUTTON())
                        
                    } // HSTACK END
                    HStack {
                        
                        Button {
                            LocationService.sharedLocInstance.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Record runs")
                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(NEUMORPHISM_BUTTON_SQ())
                        
                        Button {
                            LocationService.sharedLocInstance.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                        } label: {
                            Text("End recording")
                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(NEUMORPHISM_BUTTON_SQ())
                        
                        Button {
                            print("button tapped")
                        } label: {
                            Text("Something")
                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(NEUMORPHISM_BUTTON_SQ())
                        
                    }
                    VStack{
                        
                        Text("Average Speed: \(model.avgSpeed)")
                        Text("Top Speed: \(model.topSpeed)")
//                        Text("Top Speed: \(model.altitude)")
                        
                    }
                    Spacer()
                } // VSTACK END
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            else{
                
                ZStack(alignment: .top){
                    // show map
                    SecondMap()
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                            .frame(height: 48)
                        
                        HStack{
                            Image(systemName: "location")
                            Spacer()
                            Button("Back to home") {
                                self.isMapShowing = false
                            }
                            
                        }.padding()
                        
                    }.padding()
                }
                
            }
            
            
        } // BODY END
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Your LocationViewModel tells nobody that something has changed. I see no `objectWillChange.send()`. Why should you Map update when you don't tell the map that something changed?